# Is there a way to concatenate the parsed xml using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a way to concatenate the parsed xml using c#

Comment: Can you show a code that you have? probably you just need to remove spaces and `\r\n` from the result you have using `Remove` method.

Comment: hey valentin. i have updated my question with the sample code.

Comment: do you need the separated lines as well? If no, why not just use `Append` without all the indentLevel stuff instead of AppendLine

Comment: And if you need them as well: Just replace all whitespace characters (space, tab, linebreak ,...) with empty string: `var newresult = Regex.Replace(result, @"\s", "");`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i need to concatenate another variable (test) with the result after xml parsing.

Comment: derpirsher--- i am getting The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments error for the regular expression part

Comment: Why did you delete your code from your question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have parsed the values into a set of variables:

```
var a = "b1::b2";
var b = "id1";
var c = "1";
var d = "name1";
var e = "123456789";
```

You can concatenate them together using:

```
var together = a + b + c + d + e;
```

Alternatively, you could use a System.Text.StringBuilder:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(a);
sb.Append(b);
sb.Append(c);
sb.Append(d);
sb.Append(e);
var together = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Let me try it out.

Comment: Hey Kevin. I think i am missing something. it doesn't work as expected. Actually whatever result i receive i need to concatenate dynamically.

Comment: Start with the StringBuilder, as you parse a value from the xml, .Append it. After you are done parsing you can get the string from the StringBuilder with it's .ToString method.

Comment: correct. but i want to assign all the values to another variables after parsing and then append them.

Comment: return result.ToString();
        string result_new = result.ToString();


        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(result_new);
        return result_new.ToString();
 it didn't work.

Comment: You have to do the appends first (to get the strings into the StringBuilder) then return the ToString.

Comment: Look at the code in my answer: I put the values into separate variables, then I append them to the StringBuilder, then calling the StringBuilder.ToString method concatenates them into a single string which I put in the variable together. Then you can return together.